# General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active

Tags: php, pdo

Как я понял по неработующему коду, это делается не так, да?

```
$del = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 6");
$del->execute()
```

Ошибка

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other
unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().
Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you
may enable query buffering by setting the 
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
```

Помогите разобраться как это на самом деле надо делать.

Comment: $pdo->errorInfo(), $del->errorInfo()?

Comment: @Bookin ошибку добавил в вопрос

Comment: Покажите больше кода... Потому что так не понятно как вы работаете с PDO и чего он от вас хочет.

Comment: Вам надо освободить prepared statement оставшийся от предыдущего запроса. `$stmt->closeCursor();`

Comment: @rjhdby эта функция не освобождает, а закрывает курсор. По действию сия операция скорее напоминает лечение головной боли гильотиной.

Comment: @Ипатьев захотелось изобразить действие изображенное на вашей аватарке

Comment: @rjhdby побольше опыта, и это желание поменяет адресата.

Comment: @Ипатьев с опытом ведь как, не всегда знаешь, у кого его больше. Рекомендую все же подучить матчасть и перестать мериться длиной и толщиной